# Machine Learning Python Traceback Errors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Im trying to learn machine learning in Python, I run my code to try to get a dataset. Im following a tutorial. This is my code at the moment. This is my first to with Pandas also so I might not be the best at this subject, but I always am looking to do something new.

```
# Machine Learning
# Tutorial By machinelearningmastery.com

# Modules

from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Load dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)


# shape
print(dataset.shape)


# head
print(dataset.head(20))
```

The code above is again in a tutorial.

This is the errors in the terminal. I am using python 3.8.2, and Iterm as the terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "machinelearning.py", line 25, in <module>
    dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)
  File "/Users/tylercritchlow/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/tylercritchlow/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 430, in _read
    fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/Users/tylercritchlow/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 172, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Users/tylercritchlow/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 141, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1362, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1322, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>
```

I am running the code in a virtual enviroment. These are the versions of my modules.

Python: 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
scipy: 1.4.1
numpy: 1.18.3
matplotlib: 3.2.1
pandas: 1.0.3

Comment: I think there's issue accessing the file from that URL from your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SSL certificate error when trying to get the data from that url.

The code under the comment `#load dataset` is where the issue is. 
In order to continue with your tutorial, you can get the iris data set in the following manner.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

#load dataset
dataset = load_iris()
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset['data'],columns=['sepal length','sepal width','petal Length','petal width'])
dataset['Species']=dataset['target']

# shape
print(dataset.shape)

# head
print(dataset.head(20))
```